# What's the difference between Quagga's OSPFv2 implementation and Cisco Packet Tracer OSPFv2 implementation?

Tags: cisco, quagga

In what way/s do they differ and their characteristics that distinct them from each other?

Comment: This questions seems too broad... Can't you narrow it to specific details?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

They should not differ much (and/or at all) and be inter-operable as OSPF v2 is a ratified standard:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2328